# Rotating one Figure

Tags: vb.net, graphics, draw

I want to draw a first figure rotated and a second one unrotated. When I run the code below, it doesn't show the first figure but second one is rotated. Reset is not working. I need to keep the order of the figures unchanged.

```
    Private Sub Form17_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
        Dim x, y As Integer
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality
        'Figure 1
        Dim Mx As Matrix = New Matrix()
        x = 59 : y = 25
        Mx.RotateAt(90, New Point(x, y), MatrixOrder.Append)
        e.Graphics.Transform = Mx
        e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(New Pen(Color.Green, 1), New Rectangle(x + 3, y - 5, 10, 10))
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(New Pen(Color.Green, 1), x, y - 2, x + 13, y - 2)
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(New Pen(Color.Green, 1), x, y + 2, x + 13, y + 2)
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(New Pen(Color.Green, 1), x + 8, y - 5, x + 8, y + 5)
        Mx.Reset()
        'Figura 2
        e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(New Pen(Color.Blue, 1), New Rectangle(x + 3, y - 5, 10, 10))
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(New Pen(Color.Blue, 1), x, y - 2, x + 13, y - 2)
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(New Pen(Color.Blue, 1), x, y + 2, x + 13, y + 2)
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(New Pen(Color.Blue, 1), x + 8, y - 5, x + 8, y + 5)
    End Sub
```

What's wrong?

Comment: No clue about the first absent figure (may be it's out of screen because of rotation?).  For the second one, it's normal that it's rotated:Graphics.Transform takes a [copy of the matrix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.transform?view=netframework-4.8).  So if you reset Mx,  the old copy is still in Graphics.  You need another `e.Graphics.Transform = Mx` after the reset.

Comment: `e.Graphics.ResetTransform()`. If you use fixed Pens (same Color, size of 1), use the stock objects (`Pens.Green`, `Pens.Blue`). Otherwise, you have to dispose of those Pens (or create them outside the Paint event and dispose of them when the Form closes.) either explicitly (calling Dispose()) or implicitly (declaring them with a `Using` statement).

Answer (score 0):

The two figures are drawn on top of each other. Re-assign the matrix after resetting:

```
Mx.Reset()
e.Graphics.Transform = Mx ' <======== Add this line!
```